# Where to find a reliable weather forecast for mountain region of Nepal

Tags: online-resources, weather-and-climate, trekking, nepal

Where can I find a reliable weather forecast for trekking in remote mountain regions of Nepal?

I'm planning a trek to Upper Dolpo (east of Dhaulagiri range). Considering a recent fatalities associated with a [serious snow storm](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-29640241) in a month known for a good and stable weather I'd like to get as much info as possible.

*Subquestions:*

- Are general-use weather forecasts (such as [YR.NO](http://yr.no) or [weather.com](http://weather.com)) of any use in such a remote region?
- Are they any weather forecasts for local airstrips? There is an airport in Juphal at the edge of Dolpo Region.
- Do you have positive reference for specialized mountain weather services such as [meteoexploration.com](http://www.meteoexploration.com) or [mountain-forecast.com](http://www.mountain-forecast.com/)?
- Any other suggestions for reliable weather forecast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page covers some of the basic on Nepal:
 [Nepal weather tripadvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Travel-g293889-s208/Nepal:Weather.And.When.To.Go.html)

As it says there as well, it can be useful for all travellers to take a look at Meteorological Forecasting Division of Goverment of Nepal here: [Meteorological Forecasting Division of Goverment of Nepal](http://www.mfd.gov.np/)  to check the weather before travel.

This is a live web cam from the top of Kala Patthar, so you can see how is the weather like every minutes:

[Everest Live Webcam](http://www.evk2cnr.org/WebCams/PyramidOne/everest-webcam.html)

The second gives you the temperature, the umidity, the wind, the pressure:

[Share Everest](http://share-everest.it/SHAREEverest2011MeteoData/KalaPattar/sensorKalaPattar.html)

In here you can have the weather:

[Meteorological Forecasting Division](http://www.mfd.gov.np/weather/)

Sattelite images:

[Meteorological Forecasting Division Satellite Images](http://www.mfd.gov.np/satellite/)

Mountaineering data:

[Meteorological Forecasting Division mountaineering](http://www.mfd.gov.np/mountaineering/)

I don't think you can get better than this. You should also copy those contacts so that you can try to call them if you manage to have the necessary equipment at hand.

Comment: Thanks Alban for links. Just note: Kala Patthar data are impressive, but it's about 400km far from Upper Dolpo. Dhaulagiri data from http://www.mountain-forecast.com/peaks/Dhaulagiri are for a peak only about 70km far from Dolpo. Question is how reliable they are.

Comment: I know, they don't have many stations there... :( that is why I gave you the site of the guys over there themselves, because if anyone knows the region they are...